# How can I list devise users in a ruby on rails project using the console?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, console

I have a ruby on rails project, and I am using devise for user authentication. Is there any way for me to check for the existence of an account by email using the rails console? If not-- is there a way for me to list all users on the app in the console (similar to how I can list all instances of a DB model)?

I have a list of emails, and I want to know if there are corresponding accounts with such emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run database queries in your Rails console just in the same way as in your controller.

Imaging you have a `User` model that has an `email` attribute and the email you want to check are in an `emails` variable then you can just run the following lines in your Rails console:

```
emails = %w[foo@example.tld bar@example.tld] 
User.where(email: emails).order(:email).pluck(:email)
```

Which would return all emails that were found in the database. Or

```
emails = %w[foo@example.tld bar@example.tld] 
found_emails = User.where(email: emails).order(:email).pluck(:email)
emails - found_emails
```

Which would return all emails that were not found in the database.